# find a function$ f$ such that $\nabla f = F$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Determine whether or not $F$ is a conservative vector field. If it is, find a funcion $f$ such that $F=\nabla f$.$$F(x,y)=y^2e^{xy}\vec i+(1+xy)e^{xy}\vec j$$

I tried following the method in my book. I integrated the coefficient of i with respect to x to get $y^4(e^xy + y^4g'(y))$ and that lead to a really messy value of $g'(y)$. I don't think its supposed to be that messy, so I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. Can someone please show me the complete process here?

Comment: That is not a delta. Also please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write formula. Including a picture with three lines is pretty lazy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think a neat picture would be lazy. I explained what I tried and where I think I went wrong, I didn't realize what part I messed up until someone pointed it out.

Comment: The comment was not intended to be offending. I just like to be direct ;) The reason why pictures are not as good as written text and formulas is simply that you can't search for it. Therefore other people can't find your question if the google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to exact differential equations.

I'll write this in the form $P \ dx + Q \ dy$. Notice that

$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 2ye^{xy} + xy^2 e^{xy} $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = 2ye^{xy} + xy^2 e^{xy} $$

(check this!) so certainly this is conservative. Now we need a potential function. Do

$$ \int P \ dx = \int y^2 e^{xy} \ dx = ye^{xy} + g(y) $$

Now differentiate this in $y$ and set it equal to the other bit, $Q$.

$$ xye^{xy} + e^{xy} + g'(y) = (1 + xy)e^{xy} $$

This leaves $g'(y) = 0$, so $g(y) = C$, done.

See [here.](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~szroberson/ExactODE_SZR.pdf)

Comment: i see, I messed up when taking the partial integration of P. I made it y^3e^xy instead of ye^xy

Answer (score 1):

Integrating the coefficient of $\vec i$ wrt $x$ should have given $ye^{xy}+g(y)$. I am not sure how you got to your expression.

Differentiating this with respect to $y$ gives $e^{xy}(1+yx)+g'(y)$. Comparing with coefficient of $\vec j$ gives that $g(y)=constant$. So you have found your $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate $y^2e^{xy}$ with respect to $x$ you should get $ye^{xy}+g(y)$ for some function $g(y)$. The $y$-derivative of this has to be equal to $(1+xy)e^{xy}$...

Comment: Wow our answers were 4 seconds apart, and basically the same

Comment: wait there's another answer!

Comment: I don't know who to accept, they both point out my problem. I guess I will follow the rule of first come first serve..